# SPO News Webpart - Can I target content by SP-UserProfile properties?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, taxonomy, sharepoint-news, news-webpart

It is possible to filter content, via KQL query, on SP-UserProfile properties (taxonomy terms) using the OOTB Highlighted Content web part, however, the OOTB News web part does not offer this option. Either we can use Target Audience or static filtering from existing result values.

I know MS intentions from get way from taxonomy-based content, but isn't this a bit to much on functionality cut-off? Any known workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot use KQL query in news web part & it only supports filtering using below options:

[image]

So,  you have two options here:

**1. Use audience targeting in news web part**

By using audience targeting, you can show news content to specific groups of people.

**Documentation**: [Use the News web part on a SharePoint page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165#bkmk_audiencetarget)

**2. Use Highlighted content web part**

You can use Highlighted content web part to dynamically display news content & use KQL to filter news based on user profile properties. You can also use KQL to filter site pages & show only news pages.

You can choose the source location (such as a site or document library) and type of content to show (such as documents, pages, **news**, videos, images, etc.).

**Documentation**: [Use the Highlighted content web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd)

Comment: thank you for your well-detailed answer.

Comment: You're welcome @fallout.

Comment: I did upvote, but this is not the answer/discussion I was expecting. You just stated what I mention on the question, actually. But I'm grateful anyway. Thanks Ganesh.

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know if you need any further help on this.